# Change color of QED symbol

Tags: color, amsmath

I wanted to know how to change the color of the QED symbol.  Here is my code where I would like the QED symbol color to be changed to my defined color:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{\theta}=&\mathbf{H}^{-1}(k)\mathbf{Z}(k)\\
  \Rightarrow {\begin{pmatrix}
  x(0) \\ \dot{x}(0)
\end{pmatrix}}
=&{\begin{pmatrix}
  x_{1} & x_{2} \\ x_{3} & x_{4}
\end{pmatrix}}^{-1}
{\begin{pmatrix}
  x(t_{1}) \\ x(t_{2})
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align}
\qed
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard definition of `\qedsymbol` is `\openbox`. Just do

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\openbox}}
```

Full code (note the loading of `bm` that's recommended for `\boldsymbol`, that can also be shortened into `\bm`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\openbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{\theta}=&\mathbf{H}^{-1}(k)\mathbf{Z}(k)\\
  \Rightarrow {\begin{pmatrix}
  x(0) \\ \dot{x}(0)
\end{pmatrix}}
=&{\begin{pmatrix}
  x_{1} & x_{2} \\ x_{3} & x_{4}
\end{pmatrix}}^{-1}
{\begin{pmatrix}
  x(t_{1}) \\ x(t_{2})
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align}
\qed
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I found this worked `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\color{ocre}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}}` for a filled, colored square. And on beamer too. Any problems with it? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT I'd use `\textcolor{ocre}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}` to be sure about color confining.

Comment: Thank you egreg!